# Cycle through $_POST variables and modify undefined with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I want to look through my PHP $_POST variables and change anything that is `"undefined"` (because of how jQuery is sending it) to `""` or at least `" "` so that when the email form is submitted it doesn't say `"undefined"` wherever the value wasn't filled out (optional fields).

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something you should fix in jQuery instead. Try defining your variables before you attempt to use them.

Comment: I'd say you should rather fix your Javascript script.

Comment: Why do you need to change the $_POST-variables, change the "say" (the output). It's not a good idea to edit  REQUEST-variables.

Comment: Thanks for the ultimately unhelpful suggestions.  I'm using the same jquery ajax call and php script for 3 forms which have different requirements as far as required fields.  Thanks to @ghbarratt's solution it all works error free and cost me 1 line of code.

Comment: You'll see how ultimately unhelpful 1 line of code may be , for example if a user types the string "undefined" into a form-field. Fixing the jQuery is still a better solution, no matter what you think.

Comment: If they type the string undefined in this case I still don't want it to say undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you consider altering your javascript to handle the undefines better, BUT..

Here is a no loops approach to do it:

```
$_POST = unserialize(str_replace('s:9:"undefined";', 's:0:"";', serialize($_POST)));
```

There is also the more typical approach of using a single loop like so:

```
foreach($_POST as &$p) if($p=='undefined') $p = '';
```

Note: The `serialize` + `unserialize` approach is cool in that is does not use a loop, but the loop approach is probably slightly faster, especially when `$_POST` is large.

Comment: Wow.  That's mind blowing.  I don't even yet understand how that works :P  But it works!  Thanks.

Comment: @MadTurki Glad you like it! .. We love one-liners don't we.

Comment: One liners are great, but you might want to check out the performance hit you take calling `serialize` and `unserialize` on every page request. It might be faster to just iterate through the values with a `foreach`, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder A good point and one that I was considering posting this. Using `serialize` and then `unserialize` might prove to be slower than iterating through a loop.

Comment: @ghbarratt Although I am a big fan of one-liners (especially ones that use PHP built-ins), it seems like foreach is about 2x faster. http://codepad.org/4n4LRvLE

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Thanks for the research. (+1 from me) I suspected that might be the case, but I thought I would offer something different for consideration. I tweaked my answer a tiny bit, to put this in the answer. If the OP has a large set of post data, then they should probably use a foreach loop instead of the `serialize`+`unserialize`.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP if you use an & symbol in an foreach loop it will use it as a reference instead of a value. Changing a reference will set the original value.

```
<?php
$_POST['text1'] = 'undefined';
$_POST['text2'] = 'undefined';
foreach($_POST as &$var)
{
    if($var == 'undefined') 
        $var = '';
}
print_r($_POST);
?>
<!-- Will output -->
array(
    text1=>
    text2=>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['var'])) {
    // it is set
} else {
    // it isnt set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as &$var) {
    if ($var === 'undefined') {
        $var = '';
    }
}
```